# Create a tethering app for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, tethering

Now I know this question exists on stack overflow but not in the way I plan to use it.

I'm an IOS developer and I love being able to share internet from my phone to my iPad and Mac for when I travel. If i pay the extra $20 a month through **AT&T** for tethering I will lose my unlimited data.

One of the popular answers or "raised concerns" is that apple will not accept an app that enables tethering. Well the thing is I would just like tethering on my iDevice and if it works out I would post the project to github so other developers can enjoy the benefits of non-jailbroken tethering. Also I would not try to publish it to the app store, i know it would get rejected.

So my question is how do I write a tethering app, not like iProxy, but more like MyWi or TetherMe. 
I'm pretty sure it's possible because apps similar to that have slipped through apples reviewal process before.

Comment: You can always keep the app for yourself without posting to the appstore and you'll be golden with all your devices. I don't know how to code tethering though so i can't answer your quesiton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tethering uses private APIs, so it would be rejected by the app store. Also, AT&T would know, app or no app, whether or not you were tethering.

Also, only the Settings app can change those sorts of settings (and considering the LTE toggle, it's doing quite a bad job of it). On a non-jailbroken phone, only Settings can change Settings.

Comment: I understand it would be rejected, i would not try to publish it. As far as AT&T knowing, I'm not too sure about that, because TetherMe doesn't show up to them however MyWi Does.    Are there any publicly available apis you're talking about?

Comment: Not that I know of. Again, only the settings app can change device settings on a non-jailbroken phone

Comment: That sucks, well unless someone comes along with a working solution, your answer is checked.